# CSS columns bug (with custom font and font-feature settings)?

Tags: html, css, fonts, multiple-columns, opentype

I noticed a strange bug (at least on WebKit) on a [website](http://www.ludliteratura.si/avtor/primoz-cucnik/) I designed with custom fonts (via Typekit) and CSS columns. The text has some additional font feature settings ("calt", "liga", "clig", "kern", "onum") which I've discovered to be the trigger.

The columns have column-width and column-gap settings. When the browser window is resized so that only one column can be displayed, text is not displayed correctly (see attached pictures). I figure that the length of the paragraph is calculated before kerning and/or ligatures are applied, thus forcing some text to display outside of its container. Disabling the font feature setting clears the unwanted effect.

Is this a bug? Has anyone noticed this behavior before? Is there a known solution?

[image: columns displayed correctly]
[image: text outside container]
[image: without kerning and ligatures]

Comment: It seems fine to me, what browser (+version) are you using? It may also be to do with your browser caching old CSS so try a full reload CTRL+F5 on windows.

Comment: No, that's not it. I tested it with Chrome, version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit), and Safari on Max OS X Yosemite.
It works well with Firefox 38.0.5.